# Drop database in DataGrip JetBrains

Tags: mongodb, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

It's database drop in mongo shell, but not in Datagrip.

I want to know why. Help me.

- OS: Windows
- MongoDB shell version: v4.4.1
- DataGrip: 2020.2.3

## Mongo Shell

```sh
> use test
switched to db test

> db.Hi.insert({title:"temp"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> show dbs;
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
test    0.000GB

> db.dropDatabase();
{ "dropped" : "test", "ok" : 1 }

> show dbs;
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

## DataGrip console

```
use test;
db.Hi.insert({title:"temp"});
show dbs;
db.dropDatabase(); // Error
show dbs;
```

## DataGrip Err history

```
java.lang.Exception: TypeError: invokeMember (dropDatabase) on JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@60231c39 (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to: Arity error - expected: 3 actual: 2
TypeError: invokeMember (dropDatabase) on JavaObject[com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider@60231c39 (com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider)] failed due to: Arity error - expected: 3 actual: 2
at Proxy.<anonymous> (all-standalone.js:77453:67)
at step (all-standalone.js:77314:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (all-standalone.js:77295: ...
```

Comment: unfortunately this is [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11113) in mongo driver and we are working on it.

Comment: They just released the updated driver, it should be working now once you update yours to the latest version (v1.9).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to update your MongoDB JDBC Driver to the latest version `1.11`.

With the latest driver version your queries are working correctly:
[image: working solution]